# Bigcommerce Stencil BrowserSync Task Options

Tags: gruntjs, bigcommerce, browser-sync

I would like to add a few options to the BrowserSync task on the Bigcommerce Stencil theme. I would like to add the [open](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options#option-open) and [browser](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options#option-browser) options to open the Safari using the external url when I run "Stencil Start".

I have been looking through the source code and cannot find the browsersync task where I can add the options.

The only file that looks familiar is:
/node_modules/@bigcommerce/citadel/grunt/browserSync.js

Appreciate any help.

Comment: I think you should give more insights about how this stack actually work. People who have no experience with Bigcommerce might actually be able to help if you give more details about how grunt is used inside Bigcommerce and examples of the code.